# D3 remove click events from one element out of a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have a class in D3 say: selectors and I need to remove the click event from the selection

```
d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click',function(){
       //Remove the currently clicked element from the selection.
});
```

Ive got two problems:

1. The removed element is supposed to be moved to a different part of the page and the I need the click event on it to be removed.
2. Also, would it be possible to reinsert the removed element into the selection on doing something else, like clicking on the removed element again?

**Edit:**

Found a solution for problem 1

```
d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click',function(){
           //Remove the currently clicked element from the selection.
           d3.select(this).on('click',null);
    });
```

Is this the right way? Or is there a more graceful method?

[A Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mukilr/q57kS/)

Comment: d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click',function(){
           d3.select(this).off('click');
    });

Comment: Im sorry, but neither seem to work. Can you maybe make some changes in my fiddle? The fiddle link is updated in my Question

Comment: ok i will do and let you know

Comment: You should just need `d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click', null)`.

Comment: I think this removes the click event from all the elements. I just need the one clicked elements click event removed.

Comment: Oh I see. Well in that case what you have in your question is the right method.

Comment: @Mkl Rjv i have updated the jquery in the answer just have a look once  and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rudreshgp/q57kS/1/

Comment: @Rudresh:+1 for your answer, but, I'm actually able to achieve the same with less code. Please see the edit in my question. This achieves the same as your code using D3 itself. Now, I just need to reinsert the selection back making all the click events active again. And I suppose I just have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For problem 1, the best method(as far as I know) is to redefine the click event in D3 itself:

```
d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click',function(){
           //Remove the currently clicked element from the selection.
           d3.select(this).on('click',null);
    });
```

For problem 2, however, once you turn a click event callback to null, the only way is to redefine the click event again, perhaps recursively:

```
function clickDefine() {
    d3.selectAll('.selectors').on('click', function () {
        //Remove the currently clicked element from the selection.
        console.log('Hello')
        d3.select(this).on('click', null);
        setTimeout(function(){clickDefine();},1000)
    });
}
```

This function makes the click event inactive for 1 second on click. And reactivates this again. I'm hoping this is an effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

here is the updated jquery it will work for your case

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.selectors',function(e){
 //$(document).off( 'click','.selectors');
  if(e.target.onclick==null)
  {
      e.target.onclick=
          function(){
          void(0);
      };
     alert('test');
     console.log('Hello');
  }
});
});
```